# send a 300-400 ms pulse through serial port

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

As the title, I need to send a 300-400 ms pulse through the serial port. My sensor need such a pulse to wake up. The program that my sensor's producer provides can do so in Windows. However I need to develop a similar program in ubuntu since my project is using ubuntu.
Any pointing is also appreciated.

regards,

Comment: On what line?  Tx or one of the control lines (RTS,DTR)?

Comment: My sensor uses RS232 so I am using an RS232 to USB to connect it to me laptop. In the future I will connect it directly to the RS232 port in my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you will want to determine on what pin you want to give that pulse.  Have a look at [the Wikipedia page on RS232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rs232) to see which signals exist.  Although it's doable to send a pulse on Tx (Transmit Data) that's fairly uncommon, so I assume you will need to send out the pulse either via RTS or via DTR.

To do this you will need [ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) and this is how to do it, assuming you want to pulse DTR

```
int pulseDTR(int fd)
{
    int status;

    // get the current modem control lines status
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &status) == -1) {
        // handle the error
    }
     
    // Now set DTR high
    status |= TIOCM_DTR;
    // and apply  
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status) == -1) {
        // handle the error
    }
    // wait a bit
    usleep (400*1000);
    // Now set DTR low
    status &= ~TIOCM_DTR;
    // and apply  
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status) == -1) {
        // handle the error
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you need to pulse RTS just replace `TIOCM_DTR` by `TIOCM_RTS`.

For more information about programming the serial port I'd recommend the [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.easysw.com/%7Emike/serial/serial.html) and [the Linux serial Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/).

EDIT: based on OP's comment sending a break is in fact what's needed.  Sending a break means that the Tx line is pulled to logical 0 for a certain amount of time (and not a control signal).  This is described in the [Linux serial programming howto](https://web.archive.org/web/20150428011219/http://www.lafn.org:80/%7Edave/linux/Serial-Programming-HOWTO.txt) and is done as follows:

Using ioctl:

```
   int ioctl( fd, TCSBRK, int arg );
```

Using the tc* calls

```
   int tcsendbreak( fd, int arg );
```

Please note the comment from the [Linux serial programming howto](https://web.archive.org/web/20150428011219/http://www.lafn.org:80/%7Edave/linux/Serial-Programming-HOWTO.txt)

> Send a break:  Here the action differs between the conventional
> ioctl() call and the POSIX call.  For the conventional call, an arg of
> '0' sets the break control line of the UART for 0.25 seconds.  For the
> POSIX command, the break line is set for arg times 0.1 seconds.

EDIT2: the great thing about open source is that the sources are available :-)  This is verbatim from the minicom source, and it's really great because it shows 3 ways to send a break:

```
/*
 * Send a break
 */
void m_break(int fd)
{
#ifdef USE_SOCKET
  if (portfd_is_socket)
    return;
#endif
#ifdef POSIX_TERMIOS
  tcsendbreak(fd, 0);
#else
#  ifdef _V7
#    ifndef TIOCSBRK
  {
    struct sgttyb sg, ng;

    ioctl(fd, TIOCGETP, &sg);
    ioctl(fd, TIOCGETP, &ng);
    ng.sg_ispeed = ng.sg_ospeed = B110;
    ng.sg_flags = BITS8 | RAW;
    ioctl(fd, TIOCSETP, &ng);
    write(fd, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 10);
    ioctl(fd, TIOCSETP, &sg);
  }
#    else
  ioctl(fd, TIOCSBRK, 0);
  sleep(1);
  ioctl(fd, TIOCCBRK, 0);
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
}
```

1. I guess that Linux uses the first option, `tcsendbreak(fd, 0);`
2. The third option is also pretty interesting as performing `ioctl(fd, TIOCSBRK, 0);` followed by some sleep call followed by `ioctl(fd, TIOCCBRK, 0);` should allow you to send a break signal with a finely tuned length.
3. the second option is actually prettty nifty, because it show how to emulate a break by fiddling with the port settings and sending a string of zeroes.  It can always be useful on systems that don't implement break.

So, conclusion?  Try first with `tcsendbreak(fd, 0);` as it's the easiest, and if that's not giving a good result try `ioctl(fd, TIOCSBRK, 0); some sort of sleep ; ioctl(fd, TIOCCBRK, 0);`.  On a sane system the "emulated break" should not be necessary.

Comment: I will ask the producer for the pin I need to send the pulse and be back as soon as possible. However, as I said, I am using a RS232 to USB converter to connect the sensor to my laptop and I can still wake the sensor up from the provided Windows program, so, do you have any clue about the pin that I need to send the pulse?

Comment: No sorry, it's one of both, only the people who build the device can tell you that (or maybe that info can be found in the technical documentation for the device).  Wrt that USB converter, unless you have the shoddiest of shoddy USB-Serial converters the fact that you pass via such a converter should not make any difference, nowadays they're pretty precise emulations of a real serial port.

Comment: I just try the break from tera-term (alt-B) and it works exactly as the break signal from the provided program. Again, do you have any clue? <I am keep trying to figure out how to do it because the producer will take 1 or 2 days to response me>

Comment: in page http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsendbreak tcsendbreak() transmits a continuous stream of zero-valued bits for a specific duration, if the terminal is using asynchronous serial data transmission. If duration is zero, it transmits zero-valued bits for at least 0.25 seconds, and not more that 0.5 seconds. If duration is not zero, it sends zero-valued bits for some implementation-defined length of time.

Comment: and in page http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_tcsendbreak.htm If duration is zero, it transmits zero-valued bits for at least 0.25 seconds, and not more that 0.5 seconds. If duration is not zero, it sends zero-valued bits for duration*N seconds, where N is at least 0.25, and not more than 0.5.
then how can I know which is the duration of the break of each function for my system?